# How can I create a general purpose paging spliterator?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, spliterator

I would like to be able to process a java stream reading from a source that must be accessed in pages. As a first approach, I implemented a paging iterator that simply requested pages when the current page ran out of items and then used `StreamSupport.stream(iterator, false)` to get a stream handle over the iterator.

As I found that my pages are quite expensive to fetch, I would like to access pages by way of a parallel stream. At this point I discovered that the parallelism provided by my naive approach is non-existent due to the spliterator implementation that java provides directly from an iterator. Since I actually know quite a lot about the elements I'd like to traverse (I know total result count after requesting the first page, and the source supports an offset and limit) I think it should be possible to implement my own spliterator that achieves real concurrency (both in work done on the elements of a page AND the querying of a page).

I've been able to achieve the "work done on elements" concurrency quite easily, but in my initial implementation the querying of a page is only ever being done by the top-most spliterator and thus doesn't benefit from the division of work offered by the fork-join implementation.

**How can I write a spliterator that achieves both of these goals?**

For reference, I'll provide what I've done so far (I know that it doesn't divide up the queries appropriately).

```
   public final class PagingSourceSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {

    public static final long DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 100;

    private Page<T> result;
    private Iterator<T> results;
    private boolean needsReset = false;
    private final PageProducer<T> generator;
    private long offset = 0L;
    private long limit = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;


    public PagingSourceSpliterator(PageProducer<T> generator) {
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    public PagingSourceSpliterator(long pageSize, PageProducer<T> generator) {
        this.generator = generator;
        this.limit = pageSize;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {

        if (hasAnotherElement()) {
            if (!results.hasNext()) {
                loadPageAndPrepareNextPaging();
            }
            if (results.hasNext()) {
                action.accept(results.next());
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        // if we know there's another page, go ahead and hand off whatever
        // remains of this spliterator as a new spliterator for other
        // threads to work on, and then mark that next time something is
        // requested from this spliterator it needs to be reset to the head
        // of the next page
        if (hasAnotherPage()) {
            Spliterator<T> other = result.getPage().spliterator();
            needsReset = true;
            return other;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        if(limit == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        ensureStateIsUpToDateEnoughToAnswerInquiries();
        return result.getTotalResults();
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return IMMUTABLE | ORDERED | DISTINCT | NONNULL | SIZED | SUBSIZED;
    }

    private boolean hasAnotherElement() {
        ensureStateIsUpToDateEnoughToAnswerInquiries();
        return isBound() && (results.hasNext() || hasAnotherPage());
    }

    private boolean hasAnotherPage() {
        ensureStateIsUpToDateEnoughToAnswerInquiries();
        return isBound() && (result.getTotalResults() > offset);
    }

    private boolean isBound() {
        return Objects.nonNull(results) && Objects.nonNull(result);
    }

    private void ensureStateIsUpToDateEnoughToAnswerInquiries() {
        ensureBound();
        ensureResetIfNecessary();
    }

    private void ensureBound() {
        if (!isBound()) {
            loadPageAndPrepareNextPaging();
        }
    }

    private void ensureResetIfNecessary() {
        if(needsReset) {
            loadPageAndPrepareNextPaging();
            needsReset = false;
        }
    }

    private void loadPageAndPrepareNextPaging() {
        // keep track of the overall result so that we can reference the original list and total size
        this.result = generator.apply(offset, limit);

        // make sure that the iterator we use to traverse a single page removes
        // results from the underlying list as we go so that we can simply pass
        // off the list spliterator for the trySplit rather than constructing a
        // new kind of spliterator for what remains.
        this.results = new DelegatingIterator<T>(result.getPage().listIterator()) {
            @Override
            public T next() {
                T next = super.next();
                this.remove();
                return next;
            }
        };

        // update the paging for the next request and inquiries prior to the next request
        // we use the page of the actual result set instead of the limit in case the limit
        // was not respected exactly.
        this.offset += result.getPage().size();
    }

    public static class DelegatingIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

        private final Iterator<T> iterator;

        public DelegatingIterator(Iterator<T> iterator) {
            this.iterator = iterator;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterator.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            return iterator.next();
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            iterator.remove();
        }

        @Override
        public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            iterator.forEachRemaining(action);
        }
    }
}
```

And the source of my pages:

```
public interface PageProducer<T> extends BiFunction<Long, Long, Page<T>> {

}
```

And a page:

```
public final class Page<T> {

    private long totalResults;
    private final List<T> page = new ArrayList<>();

    public long getTotalResults() {
        return totalResults;
    }

    public List<T> getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public Page setTotalResults(long totalResults) {
        this.totalResults = totalResults;
        return this;
    }

    public Page setPage(List<T> results) {
        this.page.clear();
        this.page.addAll(results);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Page)) {
            return false;
        }
        Page<?> page1 = (Page<?>) o;
        return totalResults == page1.totalResults && Objects.equals(page, page1.page);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(totalResults, page);
    }

}
```

And a sample of getting a stream with "slow" paging for testing

```
private <T> Stream<T> asSlowPagedSource(long pageSize, List<T> things) {

    PageProducer<T> producer = (offset, limit) -> {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        int beginIndex = offset.intValue();
        int endIndex = Math.min(offset.intValue() + limit.intValue(), things.size());
        return new Page<T>().setTotalResults(things.size())
                .setPage(things.subList(beginIndex, endIndex));
    };

    return StreamSupport.stream(new PagingSourceSpliterator<>(pageSize, producer), true);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like replacing `results` with a `Queue`, and then just loading page contents into the queue?

Comment: think there are some restrictions around the "trySplit" method for ordered streams in that the spliterator returned needs to be strictly a prefix of the elements managed by this spliterator.. so the LAST spliterator to be split off for the tree needs to process the first batch of elements, so coordination of a single queue becomes challenging I think. As far as I can tell I'll need to have the first spliterator do the query, then pass it's result set to the last spliterator that is forked, and then every other spliterator can lazy query a page

Comment: Ah, ok. Are the other things `characteristics()` also requirements you have? Perhaps then the best way to go would be adjusting and passing indexes on each split (since you know the total size). So when splitting, the created spliterator would be responsible for half of the remaining(un-queried) elements, and the original spliterator would be responsible for the first half plus any pages it has already retrieved.

Comment: Sorry that it's hard to analyze, I just felt bad asking the question without providing any code at all so I dumped in some stuff I had been trying. It's the question of creating a spliterator that can efficiently parallelize against a paged source that I'm most interested in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main reason, your spliterator doesn’t get you closer to your goal, is that it tries to to split the pages, rather than the source element space. If you know the total number of elements and have a source allowing to fetch a page via offset and limit, the most natural form of spliterator is to encapsulate a range within these elements, e.g. via offset and limit or end. Then, splitting means just splitting that *range*, adapting your spliterator’s offset to the split position and creating a new spliterator representing the prefix, from “old offset” to the split position.

```
Before splitting:
      this spliterator: offset=x, end=y
After splitting:
      this spliterator: offset=z, end=y
  returned spliterator: offset=x, end=z

x <= z <= y
```

Whereas in the best case, `z` is exactly in the middle between `x` and `y`, to produce balanced splits, but in our case, we will slightly adapt it to produce working sets being multiples of the page size.

This logic works without the need to fetch pages, so if you defer fetching pages up to the moment, the framework wants to start traversal, i.e. *after* the splitting, the fetch operations can run in parallel. The biggest obstacle is the fact that you need to fetch the first page in order to learn about the total number of elements. The solution below separates this first fetch from the rest, simplifying the implementation. Of course, it has to pass down the result of this first page fetch, which will be consumed on the first traversal (in the sequential case) or returned as the first split off prefix, accepting one unbalanced split at this point, but not having to deal with it anymore afterwards.

```
public class PagingSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {
    public interface PageFetcher<T> {
        List<T> fetchPage(long offset, long limit, LongConsumer totalSizeSink);
    }
    public static final long DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 100;

    public static <T> Stream<T> paged(PageFetcher<T> pageAccessor) {
        return paged(pageAccessor, DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE, false);
    }
    public static <T> Stream<T> paged(PageFetcher<T> pageAccessor,
                                      long pageSize, boolean parallel) {
        if(pageSize<=0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return StreamSupport.stream(() -> {
            PagingSpliterator<T> pgSp
                = new PagingSpliterator<>(pageAccessor, 0, 0, pageSize);
            pgSp.danglingFirstPage
                =spliterator(pageAccessor.fetchPage(0, pageSize, l -> pgSp.end=l));
            return pgSp;
        }, CHARACTERISTICS, parallel);
    }
    private static final int CHARACTERISTICS = IMMUTABLE|ORDERED|SIZED|SUBSIZED;

    private final PageFetcher<T> supplier;
    long start, end, pageSize;
    Spliterator<T> currentPage, danglingFirstPage;

    PagingSpliterator(PageFetcher<T> supplier,
            long start, long end, long pageSize) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.start    = start;
        this.end      = end;
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        for(;;) {
            if(ensurePage().tryAdvance(action)) return true;
            if(start>=end) return false;
            currentPage=null;
        }
    }
    public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        do {
            ensurePage().forEachRemaining(action);
            currentPage=null;
        } while(start<end);
    }
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        if(danglingFirstPage!=null) {
            Spliterator<T> fp=danglingFirstPage;
            danglingFirstPage=null;
            start=fp.getExactSizeIfKnown();
            return fp;
        }
        if(currentPage!=null)
            return currentPage.trySplit();
        if(end-start>pageSize) {
            long mid=(start+end)>>>1;
            mid=mid/pageSize*pageSize;
            if(mid==start) mid+=pageSize;
            return new PagingSpliterator<>(supplier, start, start=mid, pageSize);
        }
        return ensurePage().trySplit();
    }
    /**
     * Fetch data immediately before traversing or sub-page splitting.
     */
    private Spliterator<T> ensurePage() {
        if(danglingFirstPage!=null) {
            Spliterator<T> fp=danglingFirstPage;
            danglingFirstPage=null;
            currentPage=fp;
            start=fp.getExactSizeIfKnown();
            return fp;
        }
        Spliterator<T> sp = currentPage;
        if(sp==null) {
            if(start>=end) return Spliterators.emptySpliterator();
            sp = spliterator(supplier.fetchPage(
                                 start, Math.min(end-start, pageSize), l->{}));
            start += sp.getExactSizeIfKnown();
            currentPage=sp;
        }
        return sp;
    }
    /**
     * Ensure that the sub-spliterator provided by the List is compatible with
     * ours, i.e. is {@code SIZED | SUBSIZED}. For standard List implementations,
     * the spliterators are, so the costs of dumping into an intermediate array
     * in the other case is irrelevant.
     */
    private static <E> Spliterator<E> spliterator(List<E> list) {
        Spliterator<E> sp = list.spliterator();
        if((sp.characteristics()&(SIZED|SUBSIZED))!=(SIZED|SUBSIZED))
            sp=Spliterators.spliterator(
                StreamSupport.stream(sp, false).toArray(), IMMUTABLE | ORDERED);
        return sp;
    }
    public long estimateSize() {
        if(currentPage!=null) return currentPage.estimateSize();
        return end-start;
    }
    public int characteristics() {
        return CHARACTERISTICS;
    }
}
```

It uses a specialized `PageFetcher` functional interface which can be implemented by invoking the `accept` method of the call-back with the resulting total size and returning a list of items. The paging spliterator will simply delegate to the list’s spliterator for traversal and in case the concurrency is significantly higher than the resulting number of pages, it may even benefit from splitting these page spliterators, which implies that random access lists, like `ArrayList`, are the preferred list type here.

Adapting your example code to

```
private static <T> Stream<T> asSlowPagedSource(long pageSize, List<T> things) {
    return PagingSpliterator.paged( (offset, limit, totalSizeSink) -> {
        totalSizeSink.accept(things.size());
        if(offset>things.size()) return Collections.emptyList();
        int beginIndex = (int)offset;
        assert beginIndex==offset;
        int endIndex = Math.min(beginIndex+(int)limit, things.size());
        System.out.printf("Page %6d-%6d:\t%s%n",
                          beginIndex, endIndex, Thread.currentThread());
        // artificial slowdown
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(5));
        return things.subList(beginIndex, endIndex);
    }, pageSize, true);
}
```

you may test it like

```
List<Integer> samples=IntStream.range(0, 555_000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> result =asSlowPagedSource(10_000, samples) .collect(Collectors.toList());
if(!samples.equals(result))
    throw new AssertionError();
```

Given enough free CPU cores, it will demonstrate how the pages are fetched concurrently, hence unordered, while the result will correctly be in encounter order. You may also test the sub-page concurrency which applies when there are less pages:

```
Set<Thread> threads=ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
List<Integer> samples=IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> result=asSlowPagedSource(500_000, samples)
    .peek(x -> threads.add(Thread.currentThread()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
if(!samples.equals(result))
    throw new AssertionError();
System.out.println("Concurrency: "+threads.size());
```

Comment: This is just awesome :)

Comment: Agreed, this is great @Holger. I'm in the process of wrapping this into a standalone library here: https://github.com/RutledgePaulV/paging-spliterator. I'll be adding tests, etc.

Comment: @holger This is really very good. How would it change if you don't know the number of total count of items or number of pages?

Comment: @Victor: you would need some guesswork, which requires a way to test whether a particular page index exists, i.e. is still within the limit. When you test a particular index and it exists, the range between your start offset and that index can be treated like in my answer whereas the spliterator dealing with indices above that index has again do the guesswork for the next split (using growing increments is recommended). Once you hit a non-existing index, you can do a binarysearch between that index and your offset. If you can’t probe that way, you’ll need buffering like `AbstractSpliterator`…

Comment: @marko-topolnik wrote a very good article about writing a Spliterator for an stream of unknowable length.  https://www.airpair.com/java/posts/parallel-processing-of-io-based-data-with-java-streams

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html

From my understanding the speed of spliterating comes from  immutability. The more immutable the source the faster the processing as immutability better affords the parrallel processing or rather splitting.

The idea it seems is to address changes, if any, to the source as best as possible prior to binding it as a whole (best) or in parts (usually the case and hence yours and many others challenge) to spliterators.

In your case this might mean assuring page sizes were respected first instead of:

`//..  in case  the limit was not respected exactly.
this.offset += result.getPage().size();`

It may also mean that the stream feed needs to be prepared and not used as a direct source.

There is an example at the end of the document of "how a parallel computation framework, such as the java.util.stream package, would use Spliterator in a parallel computation"

Notice it's how stream would use spliterator and not how spliterator uses a stream as a source.

There is an interesting "compute" method at the end of the example.

PS if you ever get a generic efficient PageSpliterator class going be sure to let some of us know.

cheers.